# Put label and textbox on the right of the screen CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a textbox and a label on a html page. I need to put two textboxes and two labels on the right size of the page, but I can't. I try with some answers from stackoverflow but it doesn't work too, it always put the textbox and the label down from the first textbox and label.

I put my css code:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: center;
    max-width: 70em;
}

a {
    color: #ff6f00;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.card, header, nav, article {
    margin: 1em .5em;
    border-radius: .25em;
    box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    overflow: hidden;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: .25em;
    border-radius: 0 0 .25em .25em;
}

main {
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 -.125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

footer a {
    color: #ffd740;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    width: 20em;
    background-color: #eee;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    transition: background-color .25s;
}

nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffc107;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .25s;
}

article {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: .5em;
}

article h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

article img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    transition: box-shadow .25s;
}

article img:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 .3em 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    transition: box-shadow .25s;
}

hr {
    border-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    height: 1px;
}

pre {
    overflow: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 45em) {
    body {
        min-height: calc(100vh);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    nav {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

    main {
        flex-grow: 2;
        margin-bottom: .25em;
    }

    footer {
        position: relative;
        padding: .25em;
        width: auto;
    }
}

/* Forms */

input[type=button], input[type=submit] {
    background-color: white;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    border-radius: .25em;
    transition: box-shadow .125s;
}

input[type=button]:hover, input[type=submit]:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 .3em 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    transition: box-shadow .125s;
}

input[type=button]:active, input[type=submit]:active {
    box-shadow: 0 .0625em .25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    transition: box-shadow .0625s;
}

input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=password], select {
    width: 10em;
    background-color: white;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 .0625em .25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    border-radius: .25em;
    transition: box-shadow .25s, width .4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:hover, input[type=number]:hover, input[type=password]:hover, select:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 .0625em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    transition: box-shadow .25s, width .4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=number]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
    box-shadow: inset 0 .0625em .375em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    width: 20em;
    transition: box-shadow .25s, width .4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:disabled, input[type=number]:disabled, input[type=password]:disabled, select:disabled {
    background-color: #eee;
}

input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    border-radius: .5em;
}

input[type=radio]:active, input[type=checkbox]:active {
    box-shadow: 0 .0625em .25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

input[type=radio]:disabled, input[type=checkbox]:disabled {
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 .0625em .25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
```

And also I put my html code, only where I want to put a textview and a label on the right of the screen:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main-style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <p>TEST</p>
        </header>
        <main>
            <article>
                <h1>Insert</h1>
                <form action="index.php" method="get">
                    <p>Label: <input type="number" name="Label" <?php if ($estadoBD != 0) echo "disabled value=\"$LabelDB\" "; ?>/></p>
                    <p>Textview: <input type="number" name="Textview" <?php if ($estadoBD != 0) echo "disabled value=\"$TextviewDB\" "; ?>/></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
                </form>
                <?php if($msg) { ?>
                    <p><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if($msg_estado) { ?>
                    <p><?php echo $msg_estado; ?></p>
                <?php } ?>
            </article>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <p>TEST</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want one more textview and label, at the same line of the other two, but on the right of the screen.

Can anyone helps me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your label and input in a div with a class like this:

```
<div class="label-wrapper">
    <label>My left label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

and then copy paste it and put it below it so it looks like this:

```
<div class="label-container">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
        <label>My left label</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="label-wrapper">
        <label>My left label</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use CSS to put them next to each other like this:

```
.label-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.label-container:after {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    content: "";
}
```

and then you can mixture and test things inside, like right align and such. hope this will get you underway!

Comment: great answer, I'm going to try. I tell you if it works

Comment: I put your code, on the html and on the css and it makes the same thing. I can post an Image and your code if you want.

Comment: also, I try to make changes with for example the widht or the float property and it doesn't changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Moving lablel to right

you should use style ...
put style in label like this;

```
<label style="margin-left:12cm";>
```